# Cant write letters only numbers

Tags: bootstrap, input

Hola soy nuevo programando , no estoy encontrando las clases "ZgzLDrMi" or "Y0mcjr" , supongo que ahi debe estar la cuestion porque lo que yo busco es que en el renglon del input pueda escribir tanto letras como numeros y solo puedo escribir numeros. Como hago para poder escribir todo?

```
                                <label  style="font-kerning:initial;unicode-bidi:initial;font-kerning:initial;" for="dni" class="ZgzLDrMi">USUARIO</label>
                                <input  style="font-kerning:initial;font-kerning:initial;flood-color:currentcolor;" type="text" id="dni"  class="Y0mcjr" name="dni" placeholder="" minlength="4" maxlength="8" required> </span>
                                </div></div></div>
```

Comment: Como lo buscas exactamente?

Comment: En el txt de css o en el bootstrap pero no encuentro esos nombres

Comment: de donde sacaste esos nombres de clases?

Comment: es el código completo? veo el `</span>` sin su etiqueta inicial.

Comment: con el `type="text"` en el input ya debe solucionarlo, te permitiría escribir tanto textos y números. Si deseas solo números, con el `type="number"`.